# Handlebars {{this}} shows RequestContext object and all other brackets are empty

Tags: javascript, html, spring, view, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars with Spring 5.

My template is in script tags.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="myTemplate">
this : {{{this}}}
col : {{col.[0]}}
<div id='list-content-2'>{{this}}</div>
</script>
```

My JS to handle this is :

```
$(".get-list").click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",  
                url : "getList",    
                headers : {"accept" : "application/json"},   
                data : {},
                success : function(data){
                    console.log(data.col);

                    var templateText = $("#myTemplate").html();
                    var tableTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateText);

                    var markup = tableTemplate(data);
                    console.log(markup);

                    $("#list-content").html(markup);
                }
});
        });
```

The json response is

```
{
 col:[1,2,3,4]
}
```

The statement console.log(data.col); prints [1, 2, 3, 4] and so there is no problem with the json.

But, console.log(markup); prints the spring RequestContext object and the json attribute ('col' here) is empty. console.log(markup); gives

```
this : {springMacroRequestContext=org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext@6542960e}
col : 
<div id='list-content-2'>{springMacroRequestContext&#x3D;org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext@6542960e}</div>
```

I want the col values to be printed.

I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong.

EDIT 1:

This is controller part:

````
 @GetMapping(value = {"/getList"},  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)   
    public @ResponseBody String serveList( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Model m) {
        return"{col:[1,2,3,4]}";
    }```
````